# Compare a variable and a string

Tags: c

I am trying to code a C program to start specific functions on the OS X El Capitan. 
The code looks like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        char mainchoice;
        printf(">>> ");
        scanf("%s", &mainchoice);
        if (strcmp(&mainchoice, "start ftp") == 0) {
            system("ftp");

            }
        else if (strcmp(&mainchoice, "start say") == 0) {
            system("say hello");
        }
        else {
            system("say Error")
        }

    }
```

This is just a sample code.

When I run it, it always says error via the say command. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know what does `char mainchoice;` mean in C?

Comment: `mainchoice` is *one* character. You are trying to read a whole string into its location, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So what can I do to make it work?

Comment: Declare an array of characters: `char mainchoice[10];` and change `scanf("%s", &mainchoice);` to `fgets(mainchoice, 10, stdin);`.

Comment: @haccks But doesn't that limit it to only 10 characters?

Comment: I edited my comment. Yes, I assume a string of 10 characters only (including `'\0'`).

Comment: @luistripa you can be bold and dare to make it `char mainchoice[100];` but you won't be able to successfully compare the input with `strcmp` until you remove the trailing `newline` that `fgets` places at the end of the input (if there was room).

Comment: Alright, but imagine I want to compare a string with more than 9 characters, for example 'start text_editor', will it work with the fgets method? What values do we need to raise? (Sry, I am still a beginner in C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus here:-

```
char mainchoice; //declared as a char

scanf("%s", &mainchoice); //using the %s placeholder which is for string

//for character it is %c
```

Getting the logic behind your code is you want to enter a String not a character.

Make an array of characters like this:-

```
char mainchoice[20]; //this can hold your string, one character at one index each of the array
```

Since, your are using multi word in string comparison("start say")

```
(strcmp(&mainchoice, "start say") == 0)
```

scanf does not work for multi words. scanf stops reading from the keyboard as soon as you provide a whitespace, tabs, newline.

For solving that problem, use fgets. It's the best way to read multi words or even whole sentences. **Never use gets()**! It is vulnerable to buffer overflow!

```
fgets(mainchoice, 20, stdin);
```

Comment: Ok, that worked, but then I added another line, this time with 'start metasploit' it doesn't work. It just jumps to the else part. And more interesting the other two don't work too.

Comment: That's because when you hit enter to finish input, it appends a newline in the string rather than a '\0'. Trailing newline in your input. See man fgets.
A short way is to find the length of the string and and go to the last index where newline is and replace it with a NULL character.

Comment: hahah.. you can try it at your home but not at work. It's a big NO NO.

Comment: or you even write newline in strcmp like "start say\n". Try this. This won't give you the hassle to remove newline and append a null character but it is strongly recommended.

Comment: Hit that upvote if you think it's a appropriate response :)

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring mainchoice as a character rather then a string.

use char `mainchoice[10];` to create a string.
and replace `scanf("%s",&mainchoice)` with `fgets(mainchoice, 10, stdin);`

size is 10 because you are comparing it with a string of length 9, so(9+1 null=10) 10 are enough.